# How does mongodb support WGS84?

Tags: mongodb

What exactly does mongodb mean when they say that

'The default datum for an earth-like sphere in MongoDB 2.4 is WGS84.' ?(http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/2dsphere/)

To my understanding WGS84 datum implies ellipsoid earth approximation, while it looks like mongodb is using spherical approximation.

Answer (score 1):

You are right. According to the [GeoJSON spec](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-butler-geojson-03#section-3) and [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_Geodetic_System), the WGS 84 datum surface is an oblate spheroid (ellipsoid), not a sphere.

> The default coordinate reference system for all GeoJSON objects SHALL
> be a geographic coordinate reference system, using the [WGS84] datum,
> and with longitude and latitude units of decimal degrees.  This
> coordinate reference system is equivalent to the OGC's
> urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC::CRS84 [OGCURN].  An OPTIONAL third position
> element SHALL be the height in meters above the WGS 84 reference
> ellipsoid.  For widest interoperability, GeoJSON data SHOULD use this
> default coordinate reference system and omit CRS objects.

In MongoDB, however, the S2 geospatial library uses spherical approximation. Except the earth approximation, it's the same with WGS84's meridian of zero longitude and bounds of longitude and latitude.